# Why does an accelerated charged particle emit electromagnetic waves?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, charge

Why  does an accelerated charged particle emit electromagnetic waves?

I have already seen a proof but I am looking for a more intuitive qualitative answer, such as conservation of energy etc.

Thank you!